# Project folder name is save as dependencies?

Tags: reactjs

Guys I was testing something and ended up with the following error

```
$ npm i --save react-bootstrap
npm ERR! code ENOSELF
npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "react-bootstrap" under a package
npm ERR! also called "react-bootstrap". Did you name your project the same
npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing?
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For more information, see:
npm ERR!     <https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#limitations-of-npms-install-algorithm>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Anik\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-16T08_22_43_706Z-debug.log
```

Here is what I had tried to do.
My Project folder name is `react-bootstrap` and 
I tried to install

```
`npm i --save react-bootstrap`
```

Is there any rule and regulations for that?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quit it with the back and forth. If you think the question is off topic, close vote it and move on. If you have an answer, post one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is how I solved it.

This error means that the Node module which you are trying to install as the dependency is actually your project name!

To fix that, open your package.json file and change the name of the project.